# Calling Vix API from PowerShell

Tags: powershell, vmware, vix

Long time stackoverflow reader, first time poster. Forgive me if I'm not asking a question correctly.

I'm trying to use the VixCOM API with PowerShell. I don't have much experience with either. I am aware of [VMWareTasks: C# VixCOM wrapper library & tools](http://vmwaretasks.codeplex.com/) .  I've used it with success, but would like to use the VixCOM API directly for reasons I don't want to get into at the moment. I may end up using the VMWareTasks wrapper, but humor me while I try to understand the issue at hand.

My script is:

```
$vixLib = New-Object -ComObject VixCOM.VixLib
$job = $vixLib.Connect(-1, 10, "https://esx-server/sdk", 0, "admin", "password", 0, $null, $null)
```

When I run this script from PowerCLI, I get an error:

```
Exception calling "Connect" with "9" argument(s): "Type mismatch. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020005 (DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH))"
At D:\dev\PowerShell\Automated Deploy\UsingVixCOM.ps1:11 char:23
+ $job = $vixLib.Connect <<<< (-1, 10, "https://esx-server/sdk", 0, "admin", "password", 0, $null, $null)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ComMethodTargetInvocation
```

- Which parameter is causing the type mismatch?
- What is the proper way to call the Connect method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the last two parameter types are mismatched.

To display the methods and parameter types of an object call the `Get-Member` CmdLet like this:

```
$vixLib = New-Object -ComObject VixCOM.VixLib

$vixLib | get-member
```

Returns:

```
TypeName: System.__ComObject#{94eaa428-2460-470d-8f66-2a4270aff20a}  

Name                  MemberType Definition  
----                  ---------- ----------  
Connect               Method     IJob Connect (int, int, string, int, string, string, int, IVixHandle, ICallback)
```

You may then try to:
1. Import Interop.VixCOM.dll to get the interface types
2. Create a new class that inherits from IVixHandle
3. Create a new class that inherits from ICallback
4. Create two new instances of each of the two new classes
5. Pass those objects to the Connect method

You may need to use the get-interfaces cmdlet found on the Workarounds tab here:
https://connect.microsoft.com/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=249840&SiteID=99

Comment: Wow, I had no idea anybody answered. After about a week of no response, I resigned myself to the C# VixCOM wrapper library. In addition, I've since moved on to other projects, so I can't validate if this answer works in my scenario. However, I'll mark this as the answer as it is the only reasonable solution I'm aware of.