# Shutting down VM's remotely in PowerShell 2.0?

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008, powershell-2.0, virtual-machine

I'm currently having difficulties shutting down virtual machines remotely that are hosted on a Windows Server 2008 (also a 2003) machine. My first problem is anytime I run the inital `Get-VM` command I receive the following error: `"The term 'Get-VM' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet".` All I find online are solutions to this for Server 2012 and those haven't worked for me either.  I'm pretty sure once I resolve this problem I will be able to take steps in the right direction to issuing the commands to shutdown the VMs and the server itself. Thank you for taking time to read this, and have a great day.

Comment: Which virtualization solution are you using? A 2003 server sounds like Virtual Server 2005?

Comment: The server itself is an actual 2008 (or 2003) server. However, on the machine is VMWare Workstation.

Comment: Have you installed VMWare's [vShpere PowerCLI](https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/PowerCLI/index.html), and loaded the module/snap-in? If that product even supports VMWare Workstation, which it may not.

Comment: I just installed the PowerCLI. However, I am unsure of how to load the module/snapin-in. Is there a easier way to remotely log into servers and then shutdown VM's?

Comment: You load the module the same way you would load any other module in PowerShell. But that's moot because PowerCLI [doesn't support VMWare Workstation](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-51/topic/com.vmware.powercli.ug.doc/GUID-92CD0F8F-CC26-46BF-ADE3-959159E8EB03.html) `Stop-Computer` can shut down servers remotely and doesn't require anything other than PowerShell 2.0.

Comment: Ah okay, so what would you recommend for shutting down VM's on the server?

Comment: Quoting myself: `Stop-Computer` can shut down servers remotely and doesn't require anything other than PowerShell 2.0.

Comment: Yes, but if there are VMs doing critical work  I can't have them just losing power all of the sudden unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the easiest way to do this is to download PowerCLI 4.0 and the cmdlets that are installed allow you to remote into servers with the command `Connect-VI Server -Server 127.0.0.1`and shut them down with the command `Stop-VM`. If anyone is reading this whom is trying to resolve something similar, make sure it's version 4.0 of PowerCLI and not anything else.

Answer (score 0):

VMWare Workstation doesn't provide a Powershell interface. If the guests have network access with the host, you can use `shutdown.exe` to, well, shut down the guests

VMWare has got an API called [VIX](http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vix-api/%20API), which provides a COM interface. There are examples for VBScript, C and C#, so a Powershell binding should be easy enough. I don't have got a VMWare box, so can't test it. Anyway, some success is reported around the web. [Like so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7487511/calling-vix-api-from-powershell), [and so](http://communities.vmware.com/thread/186164).